# I saved an R dataframe then tried loading it immediatly after but permission denied

Tags: r

I created an R dataframe and saved it to an RData file.  Then I load the RData file but I get error message permission denied.  How can this be?

I have been running this for a long time but we migrated to a new server, now this is suddenly a problem

```
> save(digital_fill,file="//cnd1/database/Mather Historical Engagement/nd_data_dates105.RData")
> 
> load(file="//cnd1/database/Mather Historical Engagement/nd_data_dates105.RData")
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  cannot open compressed file '//cnd1/database/Mather Historical Engagement/nd_data_dates105.RData', probable reason 'Permission denied'
>
```

but

```
> save(pcodes,file="//cnd1/database/Mather Historical Engagement/pcodes.RData")
> load(file="//cnd1/database/Mather Historical Engagement/pcodes.RData")
>
```

Comment: Are you saving it to somewhere you have write privileges but not read privileges? You might want to have your server administrator check for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But I'm able to save and read a different frame (smaller one) with no probelm

Comment: Are you reading/writing from the same R session?Are you sure the write is done before you read? Is this a very large object? There's really not much we can do to help or troubleshoot without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)